# R replace part of a string conditionally by a vector of possible replacements

Tags: r, regex, replace, gsub

Assume a data frame in R, where I have (among others) the following column:

```
V1
Q1r2c5
Q1r5c11
Q1r5_1c130
```

I have a second data frame, which looks like:

```
search    replace
5         brand1
11        brand2
130       brand3
```

What I want to do is the following: in Data frame one search for the part behind the "c" in V1 and replace it with the matched replacement from the second dataframe. Thus:

1. Q1r2c5 becomes to "brand1"
2. Q1r5c11 becomes "brand2"
3. Q1r5_1c130 becomes "brand3"

I have tried out `gsub(".*c", "", dataframe$V1")` which indeed gives me the part behind the "c". However, I have not yet found a simple way (except via for loops) to do the matching based on the second data frame.

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: try function `match` (basing the match on the part you're retrieving with the `sub` call)

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if your first column only contains "Q1r2c5", "Q1r5c11", and "Q1r5_1c130", make sure this column is a factor, then you can replace the levels accordingly. Something like: `levels(df$V1) <- c("brand1", "brand2", "brand3")`

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong: unfortunately not, the part before the "c" contains 28 different strings, and the part behind the "c" 15. So I wuld end up with 420 factor levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` to produce the replacement. In below example I add one more data to the first data frame, to check things out.

```
V1 <- read.table(text="Q1r2c5
                 Q1r5c11
                 Q1r5_1c130
                 testc130", stringsAsFactors=F)
V2 <- read.table(text = "search    replace
                 5         brand1
                 11        brand2
                 130       brand3", header = T, stringsAsFactors=F)

V2$replace[match(sub(".*c", "", V1$V1), V2$search)]
[1] "brand1" "brand2" "brand3" "brand3"
```

Comment: That's it. Nice solution, seems to be the equivalent to Excels vlookup function.